# JMeter - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I open JMeter and I see the following error in the logs:

> jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Could not instantiate
>   com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.xmlformatter.gui.XMLFormatPostProcessorGui
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   kg/apc/jmeter/JMeterPluginsUtils : **Unsupported major.minor version**
>   **51.0**

I have java version 1.6.0_45 installed on my machine, my PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables contain the path to JDK 1.6, because of this issue I'm unable to open any .jmx files as the open option is disabled in JMeter, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Java 6 ended public updates Apr 2013 and Java 7 finished Apr 2015. Java 8 will stop having public releases for commercial use in Jan 2019. I would think about how you can migrate to Java 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of [JMeter 3.0 changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) it requires java 7

> Bug 57981 - Require a minimum of Java 7.

Since JMeter 3.2 - Java 8:

> JMeter now requires Java 8.

Consider upgrade to Java 8 and latest JMeter 5.0

If you can't upgrade Java, you will need to work with JMeter 2.9 which isn't a recommended solution.

Answer (score 1):

That major.minor version issue means that you are trying to run your code on an older version of Java compared to the one it was compiled with.

If you check this [link](http://that%20major.minor%20version%20issue%20means%20that%20you%20are%20trying%20to%20run%20your%20code%20on%20an%20older%20version%20of%20Java%20compared%20to%20the%20one%20it%20was%20compiled%20with.%20Y), you'll see that that code has been compiled with Java 7, meaning the build is probably not compatible with your JRE.

I would recommend you to update to Java 7